# How to Display the results in a table format

Tags: laravel

I want to display the result of the permissions table in a table format... I'm using Laratrust for roles and permissions

my RoleController

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $role = Role::with('permissions')->with('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('admin.roles.show', compact('role'));  
    }
```

I want the results to be display in this table horizontally like the way I hard-coded it

show.blade.php

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">PERMISSION</th>
            <th scope="col">CREATE</th>
            <th scope="col">READ</th>
            <th scope="col">UPDATE</th>
            <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Users</th>
        <td>Create User</td>
        <td>Read User</td>
        <td>Update User</td>
        <td>Delete User</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Profile</th>
        <td>Create Profile</td>
        <td>Read Profile</td>
        <td>Update Profile</td>
        <td>Delete Profile</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is foreach loop working for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
<thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">PERMISSION</th>
    <th scope="col">CREATE</th>
    <th scope="col">READ</th>
    <th scope="col">UPDATE</th>
    <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   @foreach($role as $key => $data)
     <tr>    
       <th>{{$data->permission}}</th>
       <th>{{$data->create}}</th>
       <th>{{$data->read}}</th>
       <th>{{$data->update}}</th>
       <th>{{$data->delete}}</th>                 
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

> I think this should work if role variable have all the data

Answer (score 0):

You can read in Laravel docs for more information https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

And make sure in your Role model has permissions, users relationship then try this:

```php
// controller file
public function show($id)
{
        $role = Role::with(['permissions', 'users'])->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('admin.roles.show', compact('role'));  
}

// blade file
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">PERMISSION</th>
            <th scope="col">CREATE</th>
            <th scope="col">READ</th>
            <th scope="col">UPDATE</th>
            <th scope="col">DELETE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach($role->permissions as $permission)
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">{{ $permission->name }}</th>
        <td>Create User</td>
        <td>Read User</td>
        <td>Update User</td>
        <td>Delete User</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```